# The updated value from the store does not change inside the function

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I have some functional component. Inside component I get value from redux store (I am using redux-toolkit). Also I have handler inside this component.

The value of variable from store set after request to api via RTK Query. So, the variable first has a default value, and then changes to value from the api.

Problem:
The value of variable from redux store doesn't updated inside handler.

```
const SomeContainer = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const variableFromStore = useSelector(someSelectors.variableFromStore);
    console.log(variableFromStore) **// correct value (updated)**

    const handleSomeAction = () => {
        console.log(variableFromStore) **// default value of init store (not updated)**
    };

    return <SomeComponent onSomeAction={handleSomeAction} />;
};
```

SomeComponent

```
const SomeComponent = (props) => {
    const { list, onSomeAction } = props;

    const moreRef = useRef(null);

    const loadMore = () => {
        if (moreRef.current) {
            const scrollMorePosition = moreRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
            if (scrollMorePosition <= window.innerHeight) {
                onSomeAction(); // Call handler from Container
            }
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener('scroll', loadMore);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('scroll', loadMore);
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        ...
    );
};
```

How is it possible? What do I not understand?)

Comment: Can you show the code for `SomeComponent`? It's possibly holding the original value of `handleSomeAction` that it was passed (which has created a closure around `variableFromStore`).

Comment: @gerrod  Sure, added SomeComponent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you're unintentionally creating a closure around the original version of `handleSomeAction`:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', loadMore);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', loadMore);
  }
}, []);
```

The dependencies array here is empty, which means this effect only runs the first time that your component mounts, hence capturing the value of `loadMore` at the time the component mounts (which itself captures the value of `onSomeAction` at the time the component mounts).

The "easy fix" is to specify `loadMore` as a dependency for your effect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('scroll', loadMore);
  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener('scroll', loadMore);
  }
}, [loadMore]);
```

BUT! This will now create a new problem - `handleSomeAction` is recreated on every render, so your effect will now also run on every render!

So, without knowing more details about what you're *actually* trying to do, I'd use a `ref` to store a reference to the `onSomeAction`, and the inline the `loadMore` into your effect:

```
// A simple custom hook that updates a ref to whatever the latest value was passed
const useLatest = (value) => {
  const ref = useRef();
  ref.current = value;

  return ref;
}

const SomeComponent = (props) => {
  const { list, onSomeAction } = props;

  const moreRef = useRef(null);
  const onSomeActionRef = useLatest(onSomeAction);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadMore = () => {
      if (!moreRef.current) return;

      const scrollMorePosition = moreRef.current.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
      if (scrollMorePosition <= window.innerHeight) {
          onSomeActionRef.current();
      }
    }

    window.addEventListener('scroll', loadMore);
    return () => window.removeEventListener('scroll', loadMore);
  }, []);

  return (
      ...
  );
};
```